# window.open not working in subscribe angular

Tags: angular, subscribe

How can do window.open in angular when you subscribe to it? Im doing this one and it doesnt work.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    let code: string = null;
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe((result) => {
      code = result.get('code');
      if (code) {
        this.pageDataService.getQrLinks(Number(code)).subscribe(r => {
          if (r) {
            this.qrItems = r;
            this.showLinks = true;
            console.log (this.qrItems.length);
            if (this.qrItems.length === 1) {
             window.open(this.qrItems[0].contentLink);           
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers block popups if they are called outside of user-triggered event handlers like `onclick`. `setTimeout()` could help.

```js
    setTimeout(() => {
      window.open('http://google.com');
    }, 1000);
```